# HTML CSS formatting: table row inherit content height

Tags: html, css, css-tables, fixed-width

How can I format a table row to inherit the height of the content? I wish to have something like
[image]

I have tried

```
table{
   table-layout:fixed;
   width:700px;
 }
```

but that does not work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919286/autosize-html-table-cell-height-based-on-content-when-rowspan-isinvolved

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3245888/215234

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tyipcally, a table will inherit the height of the content provided that the columns have a defined width using either percentage of the total table width or absolutel pixel "px" definitions. IN addition, be sure that the table rows do not have a specified height i.e. 'height: 30px'.

Code Solution:

```
table {
  width: 700px;
}
table tr td {
  width: 350px;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A row cannot inherit inherit from the cells, as an element cannot inherit from its descendants, only from ascendants. But the calculation of a table row height takes the cell height requirements into account automatically, by the [table height algorithms](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#height-layout).

This happens in the example presented, too. Using the style sheet given and the simplest possible table markup, the result is as requested, apart from vertical alignment. That alignment is a separate issue and easily handled with `td { vertical-align: top }`.

If your page does not behave that way, please provide an example that demonstrates the issue (HTML and CSS code).